# Kvm Switch not signal monitor

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, kvm-switch

I've got this KVM switch, to connect two computers with one mouse, keyboard and monitor. I am using Xubuntu and the problem I have apart from the normal resolution problems that everyone is having (Ubuntu does not recognize the monitor capabilities), I am having the issue that the external monitor is never detected in the Xubuntu laptop, after some reboots, sometimes I get the display extended to the second monitor, but when I open Display settings only one monitor is detected (the laptop monitor)

[image: KVM 2port switch]

I am using Xubuntu with Xfce 4.10. As an extra information I could say that whenever I switch to the other pc connected to the KVM then I get another monitor in display settings in the first laptop. A bit strange. I've double checked table cables, and they are connected properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused the KVM switch doesn't support EDID communication between connected systems and the share monitor.

You should find a KVM switch support " FULL-time EDID emulation".